# Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value for 'ng-untouched': 'true'. Current value: 'false'

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-material

I get this error when trying to pass the form group from parent to child. Here the Stackblitz
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-t8qddc?file=src/app/app.component.html

This form wrapping the component is the culprit, but I cannot drop it:

```
<form [formGroup]="form">
    <!-- more form controls -->
    <idn-date-range [myForm]="form" [start]="'dateFrom'" [end]="'dateTo'" [maxDate]="max" [minDate]="min">
    </idn-date-range>
</form>
```

Any hints?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No sure exactly why this erros is happening, but you'll be able to fix it by detecting changes manually.

```
  constructor(private cdr: ChangeDetectorRef) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.form = new FormGroup({
      dateFrom: new FormControl(
        new Date(new Date().setFullYear(new Date().getFullYear() - 1))
      ),
      dateTo: new FormControl(new Date())
    });
    this.max = new Date();
    this.min =  new Date(new Date().setFullYear(new Date().getFullYear() - 1));
    this.cdr.detectChanges();
    // this.form.controls["dateFrom"].setValue(
    //   new Date(new Date().setFullYear(new Date().getFullYear() - 1))
    // );
    // this.form.controls["dateTo"].setValue(
    //   new Date(new Date().setFullYear(new Date().getFullYear() - 1))
    // );
  }
```

Comment: Can't we do this using `updateValueAndValidity` ? you are manually running the change detector

Comment: @Niladri just tried it on the stackblitz, does not seem to work. I'd be very interested in another solution.